# $CI_COMMIT_TAG in "if" statemets of regular job

Tags: docker, deployment, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I try to make a pretty basic GitLab CI job.
I want:
When I push to develop, gitlab builds docker image with tag "develop"
When I push to main, gitlab checks that current commit has tag, and builds image with it or job is not triggered.

```yaml
Build and publish docker image:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if:
        ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push")
      variables:
        TAG: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - if:
        ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push")
      variables:
        TAG: develop
  script:
    - echo $TAG
    - ...<another commands>
```

But it doesn't work as expected. $CI_COMMIT_TAG -  is empty. Despite commit that triggers job(merge commit) has tag.

Explanation that i found [that i found](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2382#note_28062132) does not help achieve my goal using "if" statements.
Solution [based on workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63370019/gitlab-ci-ci-commit-tag-is-empty) suggested here not helpful either.

It's seems pretty common job with intuitive way of using variable called COMMIT_TAG.
But it just does not work.  Can someone kind, please, explain to me how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Gitlab CI/CD has multiple 'pipeline sources', and some of the [Predefined Variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) only exist for certain sources.

For example, if you simply **push** a new commit to the remote, the value of `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` will be `push`. For `push` pipelines, many of the Predefined Variables will not exist, such as `CI_COMMIT_TAG`, `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME`, `CI_EXTERNAL_PULL_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME`, etc.

However if you create a Git Tag either in the GitLab UI or from a `git push --tags` command, it will create a Tag pipeline, and variables like `CI_COMMIT_TAG` will exist, but `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` will not.

One variable that will always be present regardless what triggered the pipeline is `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`. For Push sources where the commit is tied to a branch, this variable will hold the branch name. If the commit isn't tied to a branch (ie, there was once a branch for that commit but now it's been deleted) it will hold the full commit SHA. Or, if the pipeline is for a tag, it will hold the tag name.

For more information, read through the different Pipeline Sources (in the description of the `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` variable) and the other variables in the docs linked above.

What I would do is move this check to the `script` section so we can make it more complex for our benefit, and either immediately `exit 0` so that the job doesn't run and it doesn't fail, or run the rest of the script.

```yaml
Build and publish docker image:
  stage: build
  image: alpine:latest
  script:
    - if [ $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != 'push' ]; then exit 0 fi
    - if [ $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != 'develop' && $CI_COMMIT_TAG == '' ]; then exit 0 fi
    - if [ $CI_COMMIT_TAG != '' ]; then git branch --contains $CI_COMMIT_TAG | grep main; TAG_ON_MAIN=$? fi
    - if [ $TAG_ON_MAIN -ne 0 ]; then exit 0 fi
    - echo $TAG
    - ...<other commands>
```

This is a bit confusing, so here it is line by line:

1. If the `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` variable isn't 'push', we `exit 0`.
2. If the `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` (again, either a commit SHA, tag name, or branch name) isn't `develop` and `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` is empty, `exit 0`
3. If `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` isn't empty, we run a command to see if the tag was based on `main`, `git branch --contains <tag_name>`. This will return all the branches this tag is a part of (which is, the branch it was created from, and all branches that exist after the tag was made). We then pass the results through `grep` to look for `main`. If `main` is in the result list, the exit code is `0` which we can get with the special variable `$?` (always returns the previous command's exit code). We then set this exit code to a variable to use in the next conditional.
4. We check to see if the exit code of the `grep` from step `3.` is non-0 (that is, if `main` is *not* in the list of branches `<tag_name>` is part of), and we `exit 0`.

After all of these, we can be sure that the Pipeline Source is `push`, that either there is a tag and it's on the `main` branch, or that there isn't a tag and the pipeline is for the `develop` branch.

Comment: Thank you. Your text and my tries helped understand a little bit. It just confusing from my level that there are different pushes (tag, branch) because... well, i tag commit and do git push. Commit is uploaded to repo with tag and commit changes so..why CI could not recognize that tag is not understandable. But for now I will just accept it "ASIS". And probably will get deeper understandig of it in the future with more experience.

Comment: I had to ad `;` after `fi`, otherwise I would get
`/bin/sh: eval: line 136: syntax error: unexpected end of file (expecting "fi")`

Comment: This is actually recommended against by Gitlab, even though your analysis is spot on:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/34578#note_381469101

Comment: For the script section, is this assuming your runner is running Linux?

Comment: @tzg yes, I forgot to clarify that in my answer and will update it. If you need some other shell you can either use a different docker image or if you’re using the `shell` executor, you’d use whatever shell is present on the host (for example if you run gitlab-runner on a Windows box you’d use PowerShell). See the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) for more.