# Getting + if [[ -z "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" ]]; then + ~ ... error on Windows 10 while using the shell executor

Tags: shell, gitlab, continuous-integration, executor, postman-newman

I'm using the below code in the gilab-ci.yml file

```
stages:
    - test

newman_tests:
    stage: test
    image:
        name: postman/newman
        entrypoint: [""]
    script:
        - newman --version
        - newman run ./Postman_Collections/APIAutomation.json
```

Also, this is my below config.toml file.

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Landlord Sales"
  url = "https://gitlab.shared.pub.tds.*****.com/"
  token = "<token>"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "powershell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]

[[runners]]
  name = "AimoPractice"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "<token>"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "powershell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
```

This is getting executed for `https://gitlab.com/`  url.
I'm using a specific runner as below:
[image]
I'm getting the below error after executing the pipeline.

[image]

Also, I referred to the below solution-
[$CI_COMMIT_TAG in "if" statemets of regular job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69199614/ci-commit-tag-in-if-statemets-of-regular-job)
through which I understood that I should be using some tags (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Also, let me know if I need to make any changes to the code.

Comment: Given you're running on a windows runner, are you hosting your own runner with a custom executor? It's attempting to run a powershell script that has bash inside it.

Comment: Hi @Patrick,  I have edited my description. I'm executing on Windows 10. I'm using a specific runner with Gitlab.com.  While registering the gitlab-runner, I selected the shell executor.

Comment: You need to go and quickly re-register your runners with a new token. I can't edit your post because the queue is full (probably from people who are trying to do the same edit I am), but those token are a secret, and can now allow others to de-register your runners.

Comment: @Patrick   But why should I re-register the runner, if I have registered it properly for the first time? If you want you can answer this question if you are unable to edit it.

Comment: Coming back to this, I've not been able to reproduce your problem. I've registered a fresh powershell runner (using runner version 14.3), used (mostly) your exact CI you posted above, and the script ran fine. One thing to note is that if you're using _exactly_ what you posted above, you need to add a `tag` key to your CI/CD to ensure it's using your runner exclusively. Otherwise shared runners may pick up untagged jobs if you have them enabled. I don't think that's the issue though, since you're obviously on a windows box.

Comment: Hey @Patrick , I added tags and it is working now. But I'm getting a new error-  newman : The term 'newman' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.