# Gitlab pipelines why is CI_COMMIT_TAG null when CI_COMMIT_BRANCH exists

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, devops

In job rules you cannot do:

```
test_prod:
  stage: deploy
  environment: 
     name: $ENVIRONMENT
  script:
    - echo $ENVIRONMENT
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  rules:
   - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

According to this post: [$CI_COMMIT_TAG in "if" statemets of regular job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69199614/ci-commit-tag-in-if-statemets-of-regular-job)

"For example, if you simply push a new commit to the remote, the value of CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE will be push. For push pipelines, many of the Predefined Variables will not exist, such as CI_COMMIT_TAG, CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME, CI_EXTERNAL_PULL_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME, etc.

However if you create a Git Tag either in the GitLab UI or from a git push --tags command, it will create a Tag pipeline, and variables like CI_COMMIT_TAG will exist, but CI_COMMIT_BRANCH will not."

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

This is because git operates with tree structures and therefore pointers. Please refer to this gitlab issue for more details with comments by Drew Stachon:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/34578#note_381469101

> Unfortunately, this concept of "a tag on a branch" doesn't really exist in Git. v0.0.2 and master are just two different refs, and one of them happens to point to a SHA in the revision history of another ref. To say that v0.0.2 is on master is like saying that master is on your up-to-date feature branch.
> You could conceivably build this logic into a CI job, but it would involve detecting a tag ref and comparing the SHA to every SHA in the revision history of master and either continuing the job or exit 0-ing, or whatever. But I strongly recommend not doing this.
> I'm guessing that the tag v0.0.2 has a particular significance here by being in the revision history of master. If that's the case (e.g. you're using tags to release versions), then I recommend adopting a specific naming convention for tags that are created on master, and not using them elsewhere. The CI rule would kick off some particular job on $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v\d+.\d+.\d+$/, and it's a business rule that those tags only get created on commits in master. We use this workflow on a smaller project and it works well for us. You should also have tags set to protected in your repository if you're using them to release things.
> Let me know if that's helpful, or if there's anything I can clarify.